# Function objects in C++ (C++11)

Tags: function, boost, c++11, functional-programming, functor

I am reading about `boost::function` and I am a bit confused about its use and its relation to other C++ constructs or terms I have found in the documentation, e.g. [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html).

In the context of C++ (C++11), what is the difference between an instance of `boost::function`, a **function object**, a **functor**, and a **lambda expression**? When should one use which construct? For example, when should I wrap a function object in a `boost::function` instead of using the object directly?

Are all the above C++ constructs different ways to implement what in functional languages is called a **closure** (a function, possibly containing captured variables, that can be passed around as a value and invoked by other functions)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function object and a functor are the same thing; an object that implements the function call operator `operator()`. A lambda expression produces a function object. Objects with the type of some specialization of `boost::function`/`std::function` are also function objects.

Lambda are special in that lambda expressions have an anonymous and unique type, and are a convenient way to create a functor inline.

`boost::function`/`std::function` is special in that it turns any callable entity into a functor with a type that depends only on the signature of the callable entity. For example, lambda expressions each have a unique type, so it's difficult to pass them around non-generic code. If you create an `std::function` from a lambda then you can easily pass around the wrapped lambda.

Comment: So `boost::function` is used to define the signature of a function object?

Comment: @Giorgio The signature but not its type.

Comment: @Giorgio Not to define the signature, but to hide everything other than the signature. It also conveniently makes it possible to handle non-object callable entities as objects.

Comment: "For example, lambda expressions each have a unique type": does this mean that two lambda expressions with the same signature (say, (int x, int y) -> int) have different types?

Comment: @Giorgio Not only that, but the type is unique even with the exact sequence of tokens in two lambda expressions are identical: `static_assert(!std::is_same<decltype([]{}),decltype([]{})>::value,"these two lambda expressions have different types!");`

Comment: @bames53: I imagine that under the hood two functor classes are created and instantiated on the fly. I wonder if one could use a common super class instead of a `boost::function` but I guess this is not possible because these one-instance classes are anonymous. It should be possible for ordinary functors (non-anonymous) though.

Comment: @Giorgio That common superclass is exactly what `std::function` is. But it is not enforced, because you don't need to types with the same interface to share a common base with templates.

Answer (score 6):

Both `boost::function` and the standard version `std::function` are *wrappers* provided by the li­brary. They're potentially expensive and pretty heavy, and you should only use them if you actually need a *collection* of heterogeneous, callable entities. As long as you only need one callable entity at a time, you are much better off using `auto` or templates.

Here's an example:

```
std::vector<std::function<int(int, int)>> v;

v.push_back(some_free_function);           // free function
v.push_back(&Foo::mem_fun, &x, _1, _2);    // member function bound to an object
v.push_back([&](int a, int b) -> int { return a + m[b]; });  // closure

int res = 0;
for (auto & f : v) { res += f(1, 2); }
```

Here's a counter-example:

```
template <typename F>
int apply(F && f)
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(1, 2);
}
```

In this case, it would have been entirely gratuitous to declare `apply` like this:

```
int apply(std::function<int(int,int)>)   // wasteful
```

The conversion is unnecessary, and the templated version can match the actual (often unknowable) type, for example of the bind expression or the lambda expression.

Answer (score 3):

Function Objects and Functors are often described in terms of a
concept. That means they describe a set of requirements of a type. A
lot of things in respect to Functors changed in C++11 and the new
concept is called `Callable`. An object `o` of callable type is an
object where (essentially) the expression `o(ARGS)` is true. Examples
for `Callable` are

```
int f() {return 23;}

struct FO {
  int operator()() const {return 23;}
};
```

Often some requirements on the return type of the `Callable` are added
too. You use a `Callable` like this:

```
template<typename Callable>
int call(Callable c) {
  return c();
}

call(&f);
call(FO());
```

Constructs like above require you to know the exact type at
compile-time. This is not always possible and this is where
`std::function` comes in.

`std::function` is such a `Callable`, but it allows you to erase the
actual type you are calling (e.g. your function accepting a callable
is not a template anymore). Still calling a function requires you to
know its arguments and return type, thus those have to be specified as
template arguments to `std::function`.

You would use it like this:

```
int call(std::function<int()> c) {
  return c();
}

call(&f);
call(FO());
```

You need to remember that using `std::function` can have an impact on
performance and you should only use it, when you are sure you need
it. In almost all other cases a template solves your problem.